# Azure DevOps Build Pipeline cannot build with Tag and Path Filter

Tags: git, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

So I am having a strange event not firing when it should be.  I have a master branch and a Azure DevOps Build Pipeline.  The branch filter is set to all as `*`.  It builds.  I added a path filter with "/src/SomeFolder1" and it builds with code only checked into that folder.  Perfect.

Now I added another branch filter with "refs/tags/v*" like I've always done to **other** build definitions on other projects with NO path filters and has ALWAYS worked.

In the git repo associated with the build pipeline I created a git tag as "v1.0.0" but nothing happens.  No automatic build is being triggered.  I looked at the Microsoft documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/triggers?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#tags) and I think I am meeting the requirements.  Am I missing something?

My final CI trigger is:

```
Branch filter:
  1) '*'
  2) 'refs/tags/v*'

Path filter:
  1) '/src/SomeFolder1'
```

When I remove the Path Filter, the trigger works perfectly file.  It works either/or, but not both.

Comment: Are you using YAML for the build definition or the classic UI?

Comment: I''m using the Classic UI.

Comment: So I can get the triggers you specified to work with the catch that changes **have to be** in the path filter. Can you update the question to include the changes you made to the repo that you would expect the trigger to fire?

Comment: I made no changes to the code, I just applied a git tag at the time.  And I wanted the build pipeline to trigger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Azure DevOps Build Pipeline cannot build with Tag and Path Filter

Sorry for any inconvenience.

I could reproduced this issue on my side. And this issue has been confirmed as an issue and move to the product team:

[Build triggers from Git Tag are no longer working.](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/671682/build-triggers-from-git-tag-are-no-longer-working.html?childToView=693978#comment-693978)

Unfortunately, there is no workaround for this issue currently. This issue has been reported to product group for further investigation. After the product group fixes it, this will return to normal. It may take some time, please be patient to get their feedback later.

You can vote and add your comments for this feedback. When there are enough communities vote and add comments for this feedback, the product team member will take this feedback seriously.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Based on our discussion in the comments and my testing, the issue is the path filter. It would appear that the path filter takes priority when the rules are applied. Without a change to the actual content, the branch or the tag filters never get evaluated. With tags, no actual content is changed which explains why the build isn't firing. I verified this by flipping the path filter from include to exclude. As long as you have the path filter set, it is going to look for content change.

My suggestion would be to create a feature request for the scenario you've described or setup a separate build (I know, not ideal).

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I was using GitVersion along with an Artifact filter in the Release Pipeline.  I have a DEV stage, UAT stage, and PROD stage.  For the PROD stage I have an artifact filter set to `/refs/tags/v*` so that the pre-release artifact goes through all of the lower environments, but automatically doesn't get sent (nor notifications triggered for approvals for Production) to the PROD stage.  It works perfectly for my other projects.  And once tagged for release is should now meet the filter conditions.  I'm trying to make it as easy as possible for my developers.

Comment: I also was thinking of setting up another separate build definition with just a tag filter.  While on the subject, can you think of another method to filter the execution of the Prod stage in the Release Pipeline besides me using a Git Tag filter?  I know I can add a build tag, but I would like to follow semantic versioning thus the use of GitVersion.   I was thinking of using a "build tag"?  I developed an Azure Function that reads the BuildId and analyzes the build information using the REST API to see if it is a "clean" released build and passes the Gate filter for another project.

Comment: Or I can just read the "BUILD_BUILDNUMBER" variable in the Release Pipeline job, and not make any callbacks, and evaluate that.  The values might look like "Definition-CI-1.2.3-ci.24" or "Definition-CI-1.2.3", so use some regular expression to evaluate when it is a clean build, then set some variable, but I don't think that helps with the Artifact Filter.  So the only thing is either the git tag filter or build tag filter.